# 8086 assembly program for nCr

Tags: recursion, assembly, combinatorics, x86-16

I am currently studying microprocessors specifically the 8086 and was just recently introduced to assembly level language. I am currently stuck at the assembly level program for nCr(combination) through the recursive procedure for which the assembly level code is given below, can somebody please explain what's the logic used here, in calculating nCr through recursion.

I don't want the explanation of the whole program but I just want a basic idea about the working of recursion for nCr which I am not able to understand.

I have solved this problem of nCr through recursion(not in assembly language as I have started learning assembly recently) but with a different type of logic, that is by implementing the factorial function recursively and then calculating the nCr by using the formula of nCr, but some other logic is used here, which I am not able to understand.

This code was posted as an example on [8086{4}beginner.com](http://80864beginner.com/Sample-Code/Arithmetic-programs/8086-Assembly-Language-Program-to-compute-nCr-using-recursive-procedure.html), with no comments.

```
 DATA SEGMENT
      n db 10
     r db 9
     ncr db 0
DATA ENDS
code segment
    assume cs:code,ds:data  
start:        mov ax,data
      mov ds,ax
      mov ncr,0
      mov al,n
      mov bl,r
      call encr
      call display
      mov ah,4ch
      int 21h
encr proc
      cmp al,bl
      je ncr1
      cmp bl,0
      je ncr1
      cmp bl,1
      je ncrn
      dec al
      cmp bl,al
      je ncrn1
      push ax
      push bx
      call encr
      pop bx
      pop ax
      dec bl
      push ax
      push bx
      call encr
      pop bx
      pop ax
      ret
ncr1:         inc ncr
     ret
ncrn1:       inc al
ncrn:        add ncr,al
     ret
encr endp

display proc
     push cx
     mov al,ncr
     mov ch,al
     and al,0f0h
     mov cl,04
     shr al,cl
     cmp al,09h
     jbe next
     add al,07h
next:add al,30h
     mov dl,al
     mov ah,02h
     int 21h
     mov al,ch
     and al,0fh
     cmp al,09h
     jbe next2
     add al,07h
next2:add al,30h
     mov dl,al
     mov ah,02h
     int 21h
     pop cx
ret
display endp
code ends
end start
```

I don't want explanation for whole of the assembly code, I am just stuck at the logic behind recursion that is, I am not able to understand what logic is used for calculation of nCr. For example I know that if base cases don't match value of al is decreased until it matches one of the base cases (value of bl is also decreased by one  as the program proceeds), and the calculation of nCr is done by either incrementing it by one or by adding al to it as per the base cases.
I am not able to understand how just some addition work can calculate nCr that is I am not able to understand logic behind recursion.

Comment: Include the code in your question, and comment it yourself as much as you're able.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through it for a couple different input values?  That should help if you can't do it in your head.

Comment: yes I have tried single-stepping through the code for a couple of different input values,for 4c2 and I got the answer but I am not able to understand why is the recursion working and what's the basic Idea behind it...

Comment: Have you tried reversing it into C while you figure out what it does?  This one is weird, it uses a static variable so it's not strictly a pure recursive function.  And it only uses 8-bit operand size, so it only works for small numbers.  Obviously it either adds 1 or adds an integer to the total `ncr` as the recursion base-cases, but I haven't tried to follow it in any more detail than that.

Comment: I will convert it to C, nice idea, thanks

Comment: Or really any language, but C makes the distinction between automatic and static storage the same way asm does.  It's useful when you aren't comfortable thinking in asm directly yet.

Comment: You shouldn't have taken out the last paragraph.  It's important for questions to be specific, and leaving out that detail of which part you already understood makes it pretty broad.  I'd say too broad.  That paragraph was the reason I removed my "too broad" close vote when you added it.

Comment: Ok,I got banned and that's why in hurry I did that mistake,I am editing it..